# Do I have to learn to read the greek alphabet if I go to Greece?

Tags: greece, language-barrier

I am traveling to Rhodes and I guess that in touristic places I am not going to have to much problem but I was wondering if I'll have some trouble if I go to a restaurant or to visit some not that tourist places on the island.

I assumed that I have to learn some words or learn to identify them but I have been using some maps and the names are writen with Greek characters that is confusing so I am concerned about getting directions

Comment: I can't really think of a situation where familiarity with the greek alphabet will be useful. You might be able to read the words, but you still won't know what they mean! Consider the word κολοκύθι (kolokithi). Any idea what that is? That said, it never hurts to learn a little of the local language and customs.

Comment: What do you expect to gain from learning the Greek alphabet? Knowing that e.g. 'εστιατόριο' is read as 'estiatorio' is probably of no help at all in understanding the meaning?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo (Except that it does sound a bit like 'restaurant')

Comment: @Strawberry Perhaps it was a poor example. It means restaurant, but the words don't have much more in common than the three following letters 'est' at an arbitrary location. The words have different origins and no common ethymology. It sounds just a little bit like 'estate car'.

Comment: Good points! I am concerned about having directions, I assumed that I have to learn some words or learn to identify them but I have been using some maps and the names are writen with Greek characters and is very confusing.

Comment: It may be helpful in identifying place name signs. For example, if you are wandering down by the docks looking for the ferry to Rhodes, knowing that the name "Ρόδος" literally translates to "Rodos", i.e. "Rhodes" might be very helpful.

Comment: @Robert Columbia: Many of the road signs for places, in particular larger places, are bi-scriptal Greek/Latin in Greece.

Comment: I've travelled to Greece (and several tiny Greek Islands) over the years. My inability to read or speak Greek (while shameful) has never proved to be any kind of problem in respect of knowing where I am or where I'm going. As for road signs, they tend to look like this, I think... http://bit.ly/2rtR77h

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52653/understanding-greek-road-signs

Comment: Even 35 years ago, I can't remember even one single-alphabet road sign. Small places with monoglot menus (probably less common after EU/Schengen accession) invited us into the kitchen to point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.greeka.com/greece-travel/greece-things-remember.htm) (No. 20):

> It will be easy to communicate in Greece, even if your English is not
>   fluent. Most Greeks are familiarized with tourists and they will help
>   you if you need directions or an explanation. Moreover, most street
>   signs are in both Greek and English.....

In addition, this [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g189398-i192-k3337183-How_much_Greek_do_I_need_to_speak_1st_visit-Greece.html) forum suggests that not knowing Greek shouldn't be a problem. As the comments have suggested, it won't hurt to learn it for your personal enjoyment.

Answer (score 4):

Familiarizing yourself with the Greek alphabet is not a huge stretch and it's always useful to be able to re-recognize certain words, but....

Greece is a huge tourist destination from all over the world, especially Europe.  You will find that in the tourist areas information, signage, menus etc will be available in multiple languages.

The extent of my Greek was "Take me to [mangled but apparently understandable place name]".

Comment: Very true about learning the alphabet. It is *not* hard, especially not as hard as learning the Hebrew or Arabic alphabets. Greek is about the same difficulty as Cyrillic - lots of recognizable symbols and a few quirks to get to know. If you already read Cyrillic (e.g. as used with Russian), you have almost mastered Greek too, so go ahead and spend an evening or two and learn it! I learned both the Greek and Cyrillic alphabets in less than a week each.